# How to sync Office 2013 settings

Tags: microsoft-office, sync

I thought that Microsoft syncs Windows and Office settings when one is signed in under the same MS Account on multiple PCs. However, I need to do annoying things like enter the custom words into a spell checking dictionary over and over on my multiple devices which leads me to thinking that the sync is not working.

Does anyone know:

1. If things like CUSTOM.DIC sync should or should not be working in my scenario?
2. If it should be working, why it doesn't in my case? Is there a setting somewhere which I may possibly turned off accidentally?

Thanks.

Edit: [From this article](http://winsupersite.com/windows-live/skydrive-tip-migrate-live-mesh):

> Office settings sync (from MS Mesh) SkyDrive feature: None. **But this functionality is included in Office 2013**.

Can't find it anywhere.

Comment: I have never heard of Office settings being sync to your Microsoft Account.  Where did you read about this feature?

Comment: Open `regedit` via the Start Menu, and check what the value is for `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Common\Roaming\RoamingSettingsDisabled` It should be `0`

Comment: @Ramhound I'm quite sure that at some point, the Mesh / SkyDrive / OneDrive had the checkbox to sync Office settings. However, I can't find it now.

Comment: Edited the OP. WinSuperSite states that this functionality is supported by Office 2013.

Comment: @ṧнʊß The `Office` key is not existing under `Policies\Microsoft`.

Comment: @Borek That's strange. Please make sure you are in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`.

Comment: @ṧнʊß I am. This is the key copied directly from regedit: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft`. Under this key, I see two items, `SystemCertificates` and `Windows`.

Comment: @Borek Which OS? On Win7, I see `Internet Explorer`, `Office`, `SystemCertificates`, `Windows`, and `WindowsMediaPlayer`. Maybe your Office installation is corrupt? Go to Control Panel > Uninstall Programs > Office 2013 > Repair. Then check regedit.

Comment: It's Windows 8.1.

Comment: @Borek Then, sorry, I won't be able to help - in Win7 the registry key is there. I don't see a reason why it isn't on 8.1. Is there a Office Sync option in Settings? I think I remember about hearing something about syncing for Office built-in on Win8.1...